# Product of nilpotent normal subgroups of a group G has a non-trivial Center

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I'd like to prove that if H,K are nilpotent normal subgroups of a Group G than
$Z(HK)\neq 1$.

since the product of nilpotent normal subgroups is nilpotent, it must have a non-trivial center,so the answer because pretty easy. 
However,is it possible to prove this result without using the nilpotency of the product. If so does someone has any suggestions how to start the proof?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $H \cap K=1$ then $H$ and $K$ commute which each other and hence $1 \lt Z(H) \subseteq Z(HK)$. If $H \cap K \neq 1$, then $H \cap K \cap Z(K) = H \cap Z(K) \neq 1$ and, using a similar argument, then $1 \lt Z(H) \cap Z(K) \subseteq Z(HK)$.

So what I used is that non-trivial  nilpotent groups have non-trivial centers; and non-trivial normal subgroups of nilpotent groups intersect its center non-trivially. Note that $H \cap K$ is normal in both $H$ and $K$.